# How to export compound component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get my hands on compound component pattern in ReactJS. And all is good but I am not able to export the component the way I want.

I have created one basic Table (Data Grid), which has many component like header, row, column, search, pagination etc.

And I want the end user to import this Table in this way.

```js
import Table from './Table'

const DataGrid = () => {
     return (
        <Table>
            <Table.Title></Table.Title>
            <Table.Header>
                <Table.Row></Table.Row>
            </Table.Header>
        
            <Table.Body>
                <Table.Row></Table.Row>
            </Table.Body>
        </Table>
     )
}
```

Now in component folder, I have one index.js file where I am trying to import all component and then trying to export it in a object

```
import {Table} from './Table'
import {Title} from './Title'
import {Header} from './Header'
import {Body} from './Body'
```

Now what should I do to export in a way I want. Tried many solutions, but nothing is working.

Comment: May you share the code for `./Table`? Specifically _how_ you are exporting it

Comment: export default Table;
export { Title };

Comment: Please edit the question rather than posting code in the comments? Also, one line is not enough, please make sure the example is a [mcve]. _Show, not tell_

Comment: @evolutionxbox The reason I didn't include it in answer itself because as I said I tried many different solution already and to list all of them here won't be a better choice. And if anyone already knows what needs to be done, he can clearly tell what needs to be done for this particular situation. He doesn't need to look what I am doing wrong. (For this particular question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import everything in `index` file and prepare a new object and export it:

**index.js:**

```
import { Table } from "./Table"; // this imports from Table.jsx file
import { Title } from "./Title";
import { Body } from "./Body";
import { Header } from "./Header";
import { Row } from "./Row";

const all = Table; // <-- Here: this (all) is the new object.
// We can name it whatever we want as it is going to be a default export

all.Title = Title;
all.Body = Body;
all.Header = Header;
all.Row = Row;

export default all;
```

Now, you can use it like shown below:

**DataGrid.jsx:**

```
import Table from "./Table"; // this imports from index.js file under "Table" folder

const DataGrid = () => {
  return (
    <Table>
      <Table.Title></Table.Title>
      <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row></Table.Row>
      </Table.Header>

      <Table.Body>
        <Table.Row></Table.Row>
      </Table.Body>
    </Table>
  );
};
```

#### Edit:

This answer assumes that you have components under directories like below. Make sure to change the paths when importing if you have a different one.

```
src/
  Table/
    Body.jsx
    Header.jsx
    index.js
    Row.jsx
    Table.jsx
    Title.jsx
  DataGrid.jsx
```

Comment: I swear, I tried this approach. But don't know why it didn't work that time. Now it is working. But now I am having another issue. Whichever props I am passing to any component (except Table itself), it is not being passed. Seems like I might need to use React.cloneElement to fix this issue or something else. NVM, thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: It is working now, I was doing one silly mistake. Thanks man.